# How can i make One-to-One relationship between the CinemaWebsiteUser Model which is inheriting from the IdentityUser Model with another Model

Tags: model, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-identity, one-to-one

In ASP.Net Core MVC
here is the code of CinemaWebsiteUser Model:

```
public class CinemaWebsiteUser : IdentityUser
{
    [Display(Name = "First Name")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "please enter your first name")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Last Name")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "please enter your last name")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

and here is the code of the other Model:

```
public class OrdersCart
{
    [Key]
    public int OrdersCartId { get; set; }
    
}
```

and the FK must be in the CinemeWebsiteUser Model depending on my scenario, so i can get the user id and atach it with OrdersCart Model.
i will appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Model**

```
public class CinemaWebsiteUser : IdentityUser
{
    [Display(Name = "First Name")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "please enter your first name")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Last Name")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "please enter your last name")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public OrdersCart ordersCart { get; set; }

    public int OrdersCartForeignKey { get; set; }
}

public class OrdersCart
{
    [Key]
    public int OrdersCartId { get; set; }

    public CinemaWebsiteUser cinemaWebsiteUser { get; set; }
    
}
```

**DbContext**

```
// .....other code .....

protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<OrdersCart>()
            .HasOne(b => b.cinemaWebsiteUser)
            .WithOne(i => i.ordersCart)
            .HasForeignKey<CinemaWebsiteUser>(b => b.OrdersCartForeignKey);
    }
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: i got a problem when i named it OrderCartId is that wrong ? i got that there is a duplicate

Comment: The CREATE UNIQUE INDEX statement terminated because a duplicate key was found for the object name 'Identity.AspNetUsers' and the index name 'IX_AspNetUsers_OrdersCartForeignKey'. The duplicate key value is (0).
The statement has been terminated.

Comment: what do you mean `named it OrderCartId` ? You name the fk in `CinemaWebsiteUser` as `OrderCartId`? Have you change the `.HasForeignKey<CinemaWebsiteUser>(b => b.OrderCartId);`??

Comment: it worked in another way thank you